# Swift 2 cannot subscript a value of type error

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a json from server. I am using following code:

```
self.socket.on("contactList") {data, ack in
    let resultData = (data.first as! String).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

    let jsonResult: Dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(resultData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    let results: NSArray = jsonResult["result"] as! NSArray

    for item in results {
        let username = item["username"] as! String
    }
}
```

But I am getting following compiler error:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'Element' (aka 'AnyObject') with an index of type 'String'
```

for this line:

```
let username = item["username"] as! String
```

How can i fix it?

I didn't get any error swift 1.2 but now I am migrating to 2.0 and I can't resolve this problem.

My xcode version is 7.0 (7A220)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `results` is the array of dictionaries. Then:

```
    let results = jsonResult["result"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
```

Of course, I would recommend to safely unwrap everything instead of using forced unwrapping to avoid crashes. What would happen if network error occurs? (crash)

Comment: @Okan check again, no `NSArray` should be there.

Comment: It worked. But can you explain why this is happening in swift 2?

Comment: @Okan I think something changed in type bridging with objC. Use swift native `Array` and `Dictionary` in favor of objC counterparts. Had similar in my app but with `CFDictionary`. Vote up if I helped!

Comment: Also I have one more error like this. Do you have an idea for this? http://prntscr.com/8kbwsh

Comment: @Okan you specify `NSArray` without giving what type to expect inside that array. Specify array of what dictionary type compiler should expect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90631/discussion-between-rshev-and-okan).

Answer (score 0):

`item` is an `AnyObject`. That's not a dictionary and you can't subscript it. Following your style, you probably mean:

```
// Results are expected to be an array of dictionaries of string->string
let results = jsonResult["result"] as! [[String:String]]

for item in results {
    let username = item["username"]
}
```

But note that this is incredibly dangerous code. If the server sends you anything you don't expect, your program will crash. You really need to unload this data more carefully with `as?` to make sure along the way that you got what you think you go. Then load that data into a custom `struct` type so you don't have to test it in the rest of the program.

Comment: Why did you add the extra `as! String` there? I cast the original structure to `[[String:String]]` so you wouldn't have to keep casting each sub-component of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast item to Dictionary before.

```
if let dic = item as Dictionary {   
   let username = dic["username"] as! String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, try this:

```
let results: [String:AnyObject] = jsonResult["result"] as! [String:AnyObject]
```